# Обработка ошибок file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Допустим я получаю ошибку `500` от сервера при попытке подключиться/скачать содержимое. Можно ли как-то обработать эту ошибку так, что бы происходил повторный запрос на данный ресурс?

Comment: взять заголовки ответа, посмотреть, если там 500, то повторить? в чем проблема-то? как узнать заголовки, или что?

Comment: таким образом правда и в свой тайм-лимит можно упереться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После file_get_contents проверьте заголови ответа. Вот в оф документации есть даже примеры по нужному вам случаю http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php